# First-child control not working and issues with CSS border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to create a very simple photo album in JQuery, with 4 pics and 2 buttons("previous" and "next")
Once I get to the end of the album (meaning I'm pressing "Previous" on the first image or "Next" on the last one) the script should simply go on showing me the various pics in loop.
I wrote the code for the "Next" button without issues, but using the same code (in reverse) for the "Previous" button just won't work: once I get to the first-child of my div, all I can see is an empty border.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("img").wrapAll("<div>");
            $("div").children().hide();
            var current = $("div :first-child");
            current.show();
            $("#nextbutton").click(function () {
                if (current.is(":last-child")) {
                    current.hide();
                    current = $("div :first-child");
                    current.show();
                }
                else {
                    var next = current.next();
                    current.hide();
                    current = next;
                    current.show();
                }
            });
            $("#prevbutton").click(function () {
                if (current.is(":first-child")) {
                    current.hide();
                    current = $("div:last-child");
                    current.show();
                }
                else {
                    var prev = current.prev();
                    current.hide();
                    current = prev;
                    current.show();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        div{border-color: yellow;
            border-style: groove;}
        </style>
```

Even stranger, instead of seeing my div border covering just the single image, I get a bigger one (specifically, the images are 8x8, the border is 8x20) and I don't know how to correct it as well.

Comment: Check in Inspect Element, if it really the first child.

Comment: when I set the variable "current" at the beginning of the script as first-child, I actually get the first image. Also, the script "crashes" when it gets into the if portion of my code, so I'm sure that I've reached the last or first child during the iteration @PraveenKumar

Comment: Can you add your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a small typo in your code. In your `$("#prevbutton").click()`, the line:

```
current = $("div:last-child");
```

Should be:

```
current = $("div :last-child");
//              ^space
```

`$(div:last-child)` is looking for the last child `div` whereas `$(div :last-child)` looks for the last child of that `div`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/imclarky/ow1kaf8d/)

Comment: Can't believe it was that... Thanks a lot!